# Is the publicKeyCredentialCreationObjects supposed to be passed from the server to the client?

Tags: webauthn

I was reading about WebAuthn at https://webauthn.guide/ when I came across the sentence below.

```
    The publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions object contains a number of required and optional fields that a server specifies to create a new credential for a user.
```

Based on the statement above, does it mean that I should create the publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions object on the server and then pass it to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as some of the options will be based on policy and configuration. Please take a look at https://passkeys.dev for examples.